# woocommorce disable redirect to cart page after submit

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, cart

```
<div class="submit-group">
<button class="btn btn-green btn-large btn-full upper btn-book-ajax" type="submit" name="submit">
Book Now                                                                    
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide"></i>
</button>
<input style="display:none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-send-message" data-id="9278" name="st_send_message" value="Send message">
</div>
```

the button class="btn btn-green btn-large btn-full upper btn-book-ajax" has the same function have to " add to cart " button in woo commerce

I am looking to disable add to cart redirection after submitting

Comment: By default, no redirection takes place. If it does, it's because you enabled it in the WooCommere settings, so just disable it

Comment: Remove type and name